# Repair of internal SSD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I can no longer boot from up my Samsung EVO SSD 1TB. I messed it up while trying to install OpenCore on my MBP 2012.

I *can* reach the drive from a docking station on a second Mac.

FirstAid of either the disk or the Volumes failed.
`diskutil recoverVolume/-Disk` failed, also `diskutil repairVolume/-Disk`.

Any thing else I can do before erasing it completely + TM Restore??

Would appreciate any suggestions?

Comment: By now I tried a lot of things to get my ssd working again. So far everything failed. Even erasing which diskutil failed with "Error: -69877: Couldn't open device". Is there any way to repair this with apple tools?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can see the drive from another Mac, you could try a data-recovery program.  But I haven't tried any commercial ones myself, and was very UNimpressed by all the free ones I tried.  Still, I've heard that some of them can fix things Disk Utility can't fix.

I've also been "impressed" by Disk Utility's ability to precisely identify an error without being able to fix it.  The most recent was "bad (something) number of (large number)" and refusing to mount the volume.  Seems they could overwrite it with something legitimate and mark as free space any orphaned sectors.  It would take a long time to do so, but "First Aid" always takes a long time anyway even if no errors.

Comment: I agree to your remarks on diskutil & first aid.
Obviously the Volumes can not be repaired, because they are still busy. 
But neither diskutil nor FirstAid offer a way, to "unmount" or deactivate the drives.

Comment: Normally, when you select First Aid, the volume is unmounted, processed, and remounted, _unless_ it is the boot volume.  But often, the process reports a specific error and then says "could not be repaired."  And occasionally, it complains that a volume other than the boot volume "failed to unmount" when already not mounted!